# Custom route gives error 404 in ASP.NET MVC application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have created a login action method to log a user in, while I have already scaffolded the model and view, I am now trying to add that route to a specific page, but I get error 404 as it can't find the route.

Below is the UsersController.cs :

```
 // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User objUser)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DE_StoreContext db = new DE_StoreContext())
            {
                var obj = db.Users.Where(a => a.username.Equals(objUser.username) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = obj.id.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = obj.username.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
                }
            }
        }

        return View(objUser);
}
```

This is the webpage Login.cshtml:

```
@model DE_Store.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Mvc Simple Login Application Demo</legend>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border: 1px solid red">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.username)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.username)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And this is the `route.config.cs` file that I am using for routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Login",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 new { controller = "Users", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

My personal idea is either that I have defined it wrongly in the `Login` page or the custom route is wrong, I have been trying to use a tutorial to add the `Login` action method. I have tried accessing from another part of the web app by adding a link, but it can't find the /Users/Login route

Comment: Not strictly relevant to your question but storing passwords in plaintext is never a good idea!

Comment: Thanks, I know, it is just for demonstrational purposes at the moment

Comment: @LasSincas: Do you use the Forms-authentication? And show your `[HttpGet] Login()` code, please.

Comment: No, I am not

`    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }`

Comment: What's the point in mapping this route if you have the default mapping also there (do you)?

Comment: By any chance, do you also have an HttpGet action to show your login view because here you are only showing us the Post action? If you are trying to access the login page via a browser without it you will get a 404 error. In this case, the issue is not the route itself. The 404 error would be correct since the page does not exist.

Comment: The code was already in the comments but I have added it again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify controller?
return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard", "Home");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Las Sincas. This is how your controller code should look like. Note that you need the Login Action as Jackdaw has also indicated. That is the action that your route is pointing to.

```
using DE_Store.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DE_Store.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(User objUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DE_StoreContext db = new DE_StoreContext())
                {
                    var obj = db.Users.Where(a => a.username.Equals(objUser.username) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Session["UserID"] = obj.id.ToString();
                        Session["UserName"] = obj.username.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(objUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you only have an Index action, keep the default route as explained by Wiktor, otherwise change your mapping to this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: The above won't work. I have already an "Index" file, which is not the login page, as it is the page where I have the list of users. Should I then change the Index ActionResult to the login [HttpGet]? I Have an different actions in the UserController, plus different views for each action, so 1 for Index, 1 for Login and 1 for Dashboard